# How can I change a href attribute with javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, asp.net

Helllo guys I have a `read more` link in my page but I want to change its link via javascrpt. I am having this link `http://london/wa/al/Lists/Announcements/DispForm.aspx?ID=4` but this link does not work anymore and I do not have access to html anymore. So I need to change it to the following `http://london/wa/meridianexpress/Lists/Announcements/DispForm.aspx?ID=4`

how can I make this?

Comment: can you be more specific please?

Comment: What do you mean, you don't have access to html??

Comment: i cannot change the HTML anymore

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can try this:

```
window.onload = function ()
        {
            var allLinksOnPage = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
            for (var i = 0; i < allLinksOnPage.length; i++) {
                if (allLinksOnPage[i].href == 'http://london/wa/al/Lists/Announcements/DispForm.aspx?ID=4')
                    allLinksOnPage[i].href = 'http://london/wa/meridianexpress/Lists/Announcements/DispForm.aspx?ID=4';
            }           
        }
```

Hope this will help...

Answer (score 0):

you can add below line in any existing onload function or create one as below in any script file which you have access and already included in html

```
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById("more").href="xyz.php";
}
```

Comment: `"more"` this is the class of html or what it is. I am new to JavaScript and html sorry for my stupid question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
    document.getElementById("yourhtmllikid").setAttribute("href", "http:...");

Comment: you are saying to try this: `document.getElementByID("http://london/wa/al/Lists/Announcements/DispForm.aspx?ID").setAttribute("href","http://london/wa/meridianexpress/Lists/Announcements/DispForm.aspx?ID")` am i right?

Comment: No. You have to give an id at your HTML tag a. For example <a id="yourhtmllikid" > then with JavaScript and my suggestion you could be able to solve your problem!

Comment: i have to use `"Read more"`?

Comment: I don't understand, please give me more info